# Rename variables with illegal character Stata

Tags: stata

I have many variables whose name starts with `I:` followed by a number *n* (like `I:2390`). These are indicator variables, with value 1 for observation *n*. I imported this database from other software (Oxmetrics), so they were not created in Stata. According to the Stata Manual, only letters, numbers and `_` are allowed for variable names. Thus, Stata doesn't allow character `:` within names. Hence, I cannot run regression on them (output is `I ambiguous abbreviation r(111);`).

I'm trying to rename them all, but so far nothing works, perhaps because the name is invalid. For example, I tried:

```
rename I:2390 OUT2390

rename I# OUT#

replace I:2390 = subinstr(I:2390, "I:", "OUT", .)
```

The output is the same as before: `I ambiguous abbreviation r(111);`

Here is the output from `describe`, related to the specific variables in question:

```
I:7             double                        
I:32            double                        
I:41            double                        
I:77            double                        
I:173           double                        
I:221           double                        
I:264           double                        
I:297           double                        
I:977           double                        
I:980           double                        
I:1026          double                        
I:1232          double                        
I:1282          double                        
I:1288          double                        
I:1347          double                        
I:1429          double                        
I:1455          double                        
I:1508          double                        
I:1536          double                        
I:1709          double                        
I:1774          double                        
I:1805          double                        
I:1836          double                        
I:1851          double                        
I:1873          double                        
I:1918          double                        
I:1967          double                        
I:1980          double                        
I:2016          double                        
I:2020          double                        
I:2108          double                        
I:2109+I:2108   double                        
I:2128          double                        
I:2164          double                        
I:2173          double                        
I:2256          double                        
I:2286          double                        
I:2332          double                        
I:2345          double                        
I:3109+I:3108   double                        
I:3151          double                        
I:3211          double                        
I:3250          double                        
I:3582          double                        
I:3596          double                        
I:3604          double                        
I:3636          double                        
I:3656          double                        
I:3716          double                        
I:3718          double                        
I:3760          double                        
I:4139          double                        
I:4164          double                        
I:4172          double                        
I:4230          double                        
I:4257          double                        
I:4263          double                        
I:4282          double                        
I:4288          double                        
I:4316          double                        
I:4317-I:4316   double                        
I:4346          double                        
I:4358          double                        
I:4445          double                        
I:4644          double                        
I:4645+I:4644   double                        
I:4657          double                        
I:4679          double                        
I:4705          double                        
I:4720          double                        
I:4866          double                        
I:4899          double                        
I:4923          double                        
I:5329          double                        
I:5423          double                        
I:5717          double                        
I:5731          double                        
I:5776          double                        
I:5960          double                        
I:6103          double                        
I:6117          double                        
I:6130          double                        
I:6178          double                        
I:6182          double                        
I:6341          double                        
I:6424          double                        
I:6435          double                        
I:6441          double                        
I:6470          double                        
I:6555          double                        
I:6567          double                        
I:6668          double                        
I:6695          double                        
I:6878          double                        
I:7341          double                        
I:7349          double                        
I:7370          double                        
I:7374          double                        
I:7419          double                        
I:7449          double                        
I:7555          double                        
I:7574          double                        
I:7719          double                        
I:7723          double                        
I:7729          double                        
I:7746          double
```

Is there a way to solve this in Stata, or do I need to use other software?

Comment: This makes no obvious sense. The colon `:` is not allowed in Stata variable names. Even if it were, `rename` would be the way to change them; `replace` is for changing values of variables, not their names. See http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u.pdf If Stata allowed these variable names on input, they should not be forbidden for regression. Perhaps you are referring to something to do with Unicode. I'd recommend display of e.g. `describe` output to show what is true of your dataset. For example, you may be confusing variable names and labels.

Comment: There may be a very simple resolution to this, but a detailed answer depends on more input.

Comment: Note that your own example is further confused, as you appear to be trying  to replace `I-` not `I:`. As said, we need to see enough `describe` output to see what the problem is.

Comment: Added output from describe. I- was a mistake (amended). I am not confusing names and labels.

Comment: Beats me how you get that, unless it's a side-effect of using Unicode. As said, if Stata regards those as acceptable variable names, the next question is why it refuses them as input to `regress`.  `rename` should not be needed. A reproducible example of `regress` failing to work as desired, please.

Comment: I would like to see the results of `ds I*`.

Comment: I am importing a dataset created in Oxmetrics. The variables are dummies that represent outliers observations. Don't ask me why such a weird variable name. As far as I know, Oxmetrics doesn't allow for automated renaming of variables. Hence, I need to do it in Stata. The output of `ds I*` is just the list of the variables in columns. The output from regress X I:7 (for example), is `I ambiguous abbreviation
r(111)`. Accodring to the stata manual, only letters, numbers and _ are allowed for names.

Comment: I'm curious - by what method are you importing the Oxmetrics file? Was it written out to a flat file format, or are you trying to import the binary (.bn7) file or a .dat file? Is it possible to open the file in a text editor, select the header row, and Ctrl+H to change `I:` to anything else (or change the encoding)? As both you and @NickCox mention, the colon is illegal in Stata so I assume this has something to do with the encoding or format that Oxmetricx uses when writing the file, but I am incredibly confused as to why Stata allowed those names.

Comment: It's not much help, but at this point I suspect that you have triggered a bug  deep inside Stata as behaviour like this is a long way from documented. I don't know anything about Oxmetrics, but editing a text file before these names get inside Stata may be advisable. At some point you will find it easier to liaise with StataCorp technical support, unless as @ander2ed perhaps implies, you can make some file(s) public for people to experiment.

Comment: @ander2ed I had an original dataset in Stata .dta. Then, used it in Oxmetrics, worked on it (creating the `I:...` variables, and saved it in Oxmetrics, still as .dta. Then, opened in Stata, and voila, you have stata variables with forbidden names! Perhaps this is a bug. In any case, I solved it thanks to your suggestion: in Oxmetrics, saved the database as .csv, then easily changed characters with Find and Replace in Libreoffice, and problem solved! What remain to confirm is that variables with illegal names can be imported (done) and that they result in random errors (like r(111)).

Comment: Most of the time, this is related to buggy foreign implementations of Stata dataset standards, potentially mixed with some Stata bug. See for example http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/136809-illegal-characters-in-stata-variable-names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot make sample data with variable name containing a colon.
Try:

1. export to csv

   ```
   outsheet using EXPORTED_FILE.csv
   ```
2. modify variable name in text editor
3. import back to Stata.

Comment: This is just to note that this is an answer to the question. My first quick reading was that you were reporting a new problem, but that was wrong. I can't test whether your solution works, as I can't re-create the OP's problem.

Comment: @NickCox Of course I do not know whether this solution works because I cannot create data file having variable name containing a colon.

Comment: We agree. Not a criticism; just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the previous solution (exporting as .csv) is that you might lose the variables' labels. A possible solution is to replace all the illegal characters of your variables' names with an underline, using the code below:

```
foreach varname of varlist * {

local i = `i' + 1

if ( "`varname'" != ustrtoname("`varname'") ) {

    mata : st_varrename(`i', ustrtoname("`varname'") )
   }
}
```